# RE2 syntax: skip matching if don't share the same prefix

Tags: c++, regex, re2

I am working on RE2 and want to know how to write RE2 expression to achieve the following:

```
 desired pattern: abc*
 I want to match with abc, abcd, abcde etc
```

But I don't want to match with

```
xabc, xyabc etc
```

How do I specify it so xabc won't be a match?

Comment: @Emma exactly what I am looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We would design an expression such as

```
^abc[a-z]*$
```

with start and end anchors to make sure it wouldn't pass `xabc` and those similar strings starting with anything other than `abc`.

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/9MPuMZ/1/), if you wish to explore further or modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/9MPuMZ/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs step by step, if you like.